# Hide bottom border in css before content loads

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface

[loading issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go9As.png) I have used a label box in my div with a for loop. In label css i used bottom-border property. issue is that when page loads, Only bottom border line is visible. After contents loading that images gets visible in img tag. i want to remove border-bottom at the time of loading. [hidden] varible  is set as false after getting data through subscribe.

file data is mentioned below.

.html file

```
<div [hidden]="varible" class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab" *ngFor="let items of itemsData?.data;let i=index;">
    <input id={{i}} type="checkbox" name="tabs">
    <label for={{i}}>
      <img src={{items.imgSrc}}>
      <span>{{items.title}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

.scss file

```
wrapper {
    height: calc(100vh - 3.5em);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    .tab {
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .tab input {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .tab label {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #E9E9E9; // here is the bottom border
        margin-left: 16px;
        margin-right: 16px;
        img {
            margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
        }
        span {
            position: relative;
            bottom: 22px;
            font-size: 13px;
            color: #666666;
            letter-spacing: 0.59px;
            font-weight: 500;
        } 
    }
}
```

.ts file

```
public varible: boolean = true;
ngOnInit() {

    this.service.getResults().subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
          this.searchItemsData = response; 
          this.varible= false;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If `varible` is true until the data returned, the `label` shouldn't be visible as well, right? so the `label` and its `border`, isn't?

Comment: yes it should be like this.. but when i load page.. first bottom-border line are appearing after that.. when content loads from subscriber.. the img and item title will appear.

Comment: try `[hidden]="varible == false" `

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/dont-use-hidden-attribute-angularjs-2/) can help..

Comment: @Punj324 how did you initialize the `variable` in component file?

Comment: public varible: boolean = true;

Comment: @Punj324 still are you facing the issue? if still facing why Rika's solution is not working for you?

Comment: @Javascript Lover - SKT Rika's solution  is not working because value of varible is true or false everytime. this solution is to always keep value of hidden something so that div on which [hidden] is applied will appear or not.

Comment: @Punj324 Please check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjqezp made by me, is this what you want?

Comment: @Mosh Feu  i removed and replaced hidden with *ngIf, display:none or inhert. but still i can see bottom-border lines after reloading page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add flag for that border and set it to false by default. Change that to true after load of content.

In your html you should use :

```
<div [hidden]="varible" class="wrapper">
  <div class="tab" *ngFor="let items of itemsData?.data;let i=index;">
    <input id={{i}} type="checkbox" name="tabs" [ngStyle]="bottom-border && {'border-bottom:': '1px solid #E9E9E9'}>
    <label for={{i}}>
      <img src={{items.imgSrc}}>
      <span>{{items.title}}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

in your ts:

```
this.bottom-border = false;    
ngOnInit() {

        this.service.getResults().subscribe(
          (response: any) => {
              this.searchItemsData = response; 
              this.varible= false;
              this.bottom-border = true;
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
      }
```

EDIT: Also delete bottom border from css

Comment: bottom-border property is in label.

Comment: this is same as hidden.  if i am hidding this div.. that bottom-border should not be there.  but why bottom-border is there after loading page and before loading contents.

Comment: i just added image.. of that .. please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div [hidden]="varible" class="wrapper">
```

this line Change to like

```
<div [hidden]="varible == false" class="wrapper">
```